# Datatables column filter checkbox not working after dragging column to another position

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using datatables grid and added **Datatables Drag drop** and **column checkbox filter** feature in my grid, **datatables column checkbox filter** is working fine.

When I drag a column to another position, AND click on checkbox of datatables column Filter,  the all data from the grid disappears and the message "No matching records found" is displayed.

Here is my code:

```
$('#Table1').dataTable({
        "aLengthMenu": [3, 10, 50, 100],
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "ajaxSource": "../js/Group.JSON",
        dom: 'RC<"clear">lfrtip',
        fnInitComplete: function () {
            this.columnFilter({
                sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
                aoColumns:
                [

                    { type: "checkbox", values: null },
                    { type: "checkbox", values: null },
                    { type: "checkbox", values: null },
                    { type: "checkbox", values: null },
                    { type: "checkbox", values: null },
                    { type: "checkbox", values: null }
                ]
            })
        }
    });
```

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? It doesn't appear, you can't check the boxes, or it doesn't filter?

Comment: thank you for your response:),  after drag column then I click checkbox, all data from the grid remove and it show message "No matching records found"

Answer (score 1):

Finally I resolved the mentioned issue myself, I posting here the solution for those who got this issue
we need to open jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js and find the following function:
roughly line number is 565
 function fnCreateCheckbox(oTable, aData)
in the very end of this function 
you will find 
oTable.fnFilter(search, index, true, false);

you need just replace the parameter 'index' with this.value
your problem will be resolve..

after this the reset button won't work, so don't worry about this just go to roughtly line number 590

you will find Jquery UI dialog plugin which have same method which you changed above 
 oTable.fnFilter('', index, true, false);
you need just replace the parameter 'index' with this.value